# Adding css to a div when something is not present jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a somewhat complicated note system going on my website via ajax. When a new note is submitted anyone has an option to either reply to it or close it.

If they reply then a div with a class of reply is attached to the note and the reply and close buttons move to that note.

To keep my styles correct I need to be able to add a background to the box that is holding the buttons when there are no replies, but remove that background when there are replies.

my html looks like this

```
<div class="noteCont">
 <div class="topContainer">
  <p class="span8">
   <span>{{ $project_note->title }}</span>
  </p>
  <p class="pull-right note">date</p>
  <p class="clearfix"></p>
 </div><!--.topContainer-->
 <div class="memo">
  <p>name</p>
  <p class="noteContent"></p>
   @if($project_note->is_read)
     <p class="pull-right check">
      {{ date&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="icon-thumbs-up"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>Read</span>
   </p>

  <div class="replyForm">
   <div class="replyButtons">
    {{ Form::open(['route'=>['note.update', $project_note->id], 'class' => 'pull-right reply_buttons']) }}
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-blue replyBtn" name="" value="Reply" />
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-red closeBtn" name="" value="Close" />
    {{ Form::close() }}
    <p class="clearfix"></p>
  </div> <!-- .replyButtons -->

  <div class="reply">
   reply content here
  </div><!--.reply-->
</div><!--.noteCont-->
```

So basically if there are no reply divs within the the individual noteCont divs then add a background color to the reply form. How would I go about doing this? Any help would be wonderful!

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

Comment: Can you maybe trim your HTML a bit to the most relevant parts? It's quite a lot to read

Comment: if ( $('.noteCont')).find('div.reply').length == 0 ) // change color here

Comment: @lethal-guitar this is the trimmed down html, the real thing is three pages long....

Comment: @LorDex that unfortunately did not work...and you have one too many bracket after .noteCont there.

Comment: @Rooster I'm not trying to add a class...I'm trying to add a style.

Comment: @LorDex looking at it more, that doesn't work because there are no reply classes until someone does reply.

Comment: @zazvorniki You can always use a class to define that style. Otherwise, there's http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: @lethal-guitar I've been trying that, my issue is trying to figure out when to add that .css...not actually the syntax of it.

Comment: @zazvorniki I see.. Well, couldn't you do it in the AJAX success callback?

Comment: @lethal-guitar I can't because this is really on when page first loads.

Comment: So `div.replyForm` will be inside `div.reply` if there is a reply, otherwise not? Then maybe you could define some CSS along the lines of `div.reply div.replyForm { background: /* your bg */ }`?

Comment: @lethal-guitar no, .replyForm is not actually inside the .reply it sits outside it. This was done so that we could just attach it to the last reply instead of adding in unnecessarily to every reply.

Comment: What server-side environment (language, framework etc.) are you using? I can't tell from your source, but I'm sure this is should be done on the server-side

Comment: @lethal-guitar We're using Larval and I'm part of a team. I'm the front end person and the backend person dumped this on me as a front end issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate over each noteCont, adding the class if there are replies, like so:

```
$('.noteCont').each(function(){
  //look for replies.
  if(!($(this).find('.reply').length)){
    //there are no replies - add a background colour.
    $(this).find('.replyForm').css('background-color', 'red');
  }
});
```

**NOTE:** this will only add a background colour - if you need to also remove background colour (for example if you'd call this again after a reply has been added), then you need to put a corresponding `else` statement in there.